# firefox image link style problems (see pics)

Tags: css, firefox, hyperlink

I have some funky Firefox issues going on...

Here is what my web page looks like in Chrome/Safari:  http://grab.by/5ok9
Here is what my web page looks like in Firefox:  http://grab.by/5oke

It's applying some undesirable styling on my 2 image links.  Anyone know why and how to turn this off (the ugly purple box)?

Thanks...

Comment: I wanted to upvote this question, but the broken links make me unhappy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an img is linked, then by default the browser shows the blue border around it. to avoid this, you can use this css rule:

`a img { border:0 none;}`

Answer (score 0):

In your css put:

```
img {
   border: 0;
}
```

Those images are linked, and linked images have a 2px border placed around them.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding     style="border:none;" to the images.